# C# Getting XML SOAP response from autogenerated Reference.cs in Visual Studio

Tags: c#, wsdl, web-reference

In visual studio 2008 using .net 3.5 i have consumed a WSDL which has automatically generated a Reference.cs. 
This was done by right clicking on References in my project and selecting "Add Web Reference"

Using this i can post to the web service and get valid responses through my ref and out objects. postValues() is a void method.

```
webService.postValues(ref value1, ref value2, out value3);
```

Using WireShark i can see the the request and full soap response on my network.

What im trying to figure out is how can i capture this raw SOAP response in my code.
I would like to capture this for logging purposes and would rather not individually serialize each of the ref objects.

I cant see anyway to do this without modifying the automatically generated Reference.cs which id rather not do. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Edit: There doesnt seem to be a way to do this that i can see. Can anyone else confirm or deny this?

EDIT. Ill bump this just one more time to see if anyone knows.

Comment: Does this person's approach work for you? http://orbinary.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2010/XmlWriterSpy.cs

Answer (score 2):

You have following options:

1. [Enable tracing](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb885203%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) for your web service in config, and dump all information into file. If you are using WCF instead of legacy web services, see this question on [how to enable tracing for WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2336810/server-side-tracing-of-soap-messages-for-wcf-service).
2. [Implement your own SoapExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.services.protocols.soapextension.aspx) and plug into message processing pipeline to intercept and dump incoming/outgoing soap messages. I think example in linked artice contain TraceExtension, which does exactly that.
3. Modify generated Reference.cs and dump passed objects, as you specified.