# C# Getting Soap response from an auto generated reference.cs generated using wsdl

Tags: c#, web-services, soap, wsdl

The SOAP service I am consuming will send back a 202 Accepted. All I want to do is capture this 202 so I can confirm that the server received the message.

I have found this:
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415607/c-sharp-getting-xml-soap-response-from-autogenerated-reference-cs-in-visual-stud)

So the answer states to implement a soapextension and links to msdn. I looked at the sample code, and I am having a hard time understanding what I should do. The client that was generated submits the data in the following way:

```
psrs.SubmitPersonSearchRequest(psrt);
```

and has a void return. How do I get the response from the server?

I was able to see the correct response in soapui and in fiddler.

Comment: Take a look at this stackoverflow.com/questions/1815650/…, you may looking for http header response which you see it in fiddler

Comment: hrmm, well I know I get a response, but the method returns void.